# How to store elements in Array during runtime without knowing array size during initialization in Java? You cannot use Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dynamic-arrays

```
static int[] evenFactorsOfNum(int num) {
    
    int[] result = {}; // need help in this line
    
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i = i + 2) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            result[index] = i;
            index++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In this code snippet, I needed to store the even factors of given numbers in an array and return it. But it is not known how many factors will be possible of that number so we can't specify the size of array during array declaration. How do we handle it without storing the even factors in `ArrayList` (Collections in Java)? One restricted condition is we cannot initialize array size explicitly.

How do we achieve this dynamic behaviour of array without `Arraylist`?

Comment: oh yea, my bad! that should be  if(num % i == 0), anyway my question was on declaring array size without knowing size on hand.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the maximum number of even factors the number can have and use that as the array size. After the loop is complete, `index` is the number of even factors; you can use `Arrays.copyOfRange` (or a loop) to create an array with the correct size.

```
static int[] evenFactorsOfNum(int num) {
    int[] result = new int[num / 2];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i += 2) {
        if(num % i == 0) result[index++] = i;
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(result, 0, index);
}
```

`IntStream.iterate` can also be used to avoid an explicit array creation.

```
static int[] evenFactorsOfNum(int num) {
    return IntStream.iterate(2, i -> i + 2).limit(num / 2)
      .filter(i -> num % i == 0).toArray();
}
```

Comment: *"One restricted condition is we cannot initialize array size explicitly."* I think your solution violates that constraint.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I believe that was meant to prevent hardcoding the size.

Comment: yea, I want to prevent hardcoding array size. @iota in your approach, you are still using array of size num/2 which will be use of extra spaces, so I was looking to avoid that random sufficient initialization of array size.

Comment: @NirmalSilwal Look at the second solution I provided.

Comment: @iota I am afraid, but I was not allowed to use any inbuilt function like that

Comment: @NirmalSilwal Okay, you can use two loops then. First, loop once to get the number of even factors. Then create an array of that size and loop again to populate the array with the factors.

Answer (score 0):

An array in Java must be initialized with a fixed size. It can't be re-sized later.

You may create an array with some random size, and once it will be filled and you stil during your loop - create a new one with a larger size (let's say - double of the current array size) and copy all of the elements you poplutaed so far.